# Format datetime gap on Pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, datetime

I am trying to visualize measured data using Pyplot.
The data is stored in a dataframe from Pandas like this:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnuIR.png)

So I want to plot the outputs over the respective date and time.
Just plotting it works great, however there is an issue that I cannot fix.
Sometimes the measurements are stopped and resumed at later time. That means that during some measurements there is a gap in the date (e.g. 1 or 2 days skipped).
When I now plot the above dataframe, there is a large region that is skipped due to no data being present.
[Graph with gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXbt8.png)
Is there any way to change that, so the gap is closed and all the data is presented in a better way?

Comment: Please provide sample data along with your code. What is your definition of presenting data "in a better way" beyond "closing the gap"?

Comment: plot the values against a categorial x-axis instead of datetime. that means you'll need to convert (format) datetime to string before creating the plot. if you need a concrete illustrations, provide example data as text, not image.